# Android source code tree structure

Tags: android, android-source

I have downloaded Android source code but I don't find the "Kernel Directory"  in the top level directory of the source code tree. Is it ok? Or is it missing?

```
/mydroid$ find . -name kernel
./bionic/libc/kernel
./vendor/htc/sapphire-open/kernel
./vendor/htc/dream-open/kernel
./dalvik/libcore/luni-kernel/src/test/java/tests/api/org/apache/harmony/kernel
./dalvik/libcore/luni-kernel/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/kernel
./prebuilt/android-arm/kernel
./prebuilt/android-x86/kernel
./device/htc/passion/kernel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`default.xml` in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest does not point to the kernel, so repo would not automatically download it. Most kernel trees are specific to machines anyway.

See http://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Download for information on getting the right kernel.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git kernel
```

Comment: Is it a must to download the kernel source code before performing the build process.

Comment: I have built the entire tree without downloading a kernel. The kernel headers used are in userspace (in bionic for example), The emulator AFAIK has its own kernel to boot. To boot it in a specific machine, you will need to build a kernel for it, and that kernel headers would need to match those copied to userspace so that userland tools work.